# Regular Expressions: How to get any of a string (in order)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out a better way of writing this regex:

`/(_x0020_)|(_x0020)|(_x002)|(_x00)|(_x0)|(_x)|(_)/g`

So I want it to grab any of `_x0020_` from the first `_` on.

I appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? Do you have an example of the input string? If you just want parts of the string, why not just use `substring`? It's easier and more obvious.

Comment: This matches any and all of the sequence? Are you sure that's what you intend?

Comment: try `/(_(x(0(0(2(0_?)?)?)?)?)?)/g`— not sure it's "better" though/

Comment: Also, I would expand the question to define whether you want all _x0020_ in one Match, all _x0020_ in separate Matches (in .NET, a MatchCollection), or you just want one _x0020_

Comment: @VivinPaliath, a string could be "`Survey_x0020_Answers_x0`"  And I'm just looking for a way to get rid of the `_x0020_` and the `_x0` at the end in one statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
/(_(?:x(?:0(?:0(?:2(?:0(?:_)?)?)?)?)?)?)/g
```

Comment: I don't know if this is any "better" ;). +1 anyway

Comment: I'd argue that it's better from a maintainability standpoint (if the string sequence were to change to `_x1020_` for example, only the one digit needs to change)

Comment: Thanks, a lot.  I'm pretty green when it comes to regex and figured there was a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest I could think of:

`/_x0020_?|_x002?|_x0?|_/g`

Do not really know why there are all that brackets in your expression. Maybe I did not understand your real purpose of the regex.